# Use computed value in element using less.js

Tags: less

Have the following bit of code:

```
generate-margins(4);

.generate-margins(@n, @i: 1) when (@i =< @n) {
  .marginleft@{i} {
    margin-left: (5px * @i);
  }
  .marginright(5*@{i}) {
    margin-right: (5px * @i);
  }

  .generate-margins(@n, (@i + 1));
}
```

Which gives me:

```
.marginleft1 {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.marginright(5*1) {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.marginleft2 {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.marginright(5*2) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.marginleft3 {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.marginright(5*3) {
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.marginleft4 {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.marginright(5*4) {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

What I wanted was:

```
.marginright5 {... }
.marginright10 {... }
...
```

How can use computed value in element name? I tried using all string functions with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Did some more testing and came up with this:

```
  .generate-margins(@n, @i: 1) when (@i =< @n) {
    @l : @i*5;
  .marginleft@{l} {
    margin-left: (5px * @i);
  }
  .marginright@{l} {
    margin-right: (5px * @i);
  }

  .generate-margins(@n, (@i + 1));
}
```

Would still like to know if there is another way.  Cheers.

Comment: Well, no, you can't use any expressions in selector. Only variables.